# Getting the .so files list using packagemanager

Tags: android, package-managers

Is there way to get libs/nativearch/<.so files>  listed from the package-manager. Considering that apps like apk-info do it, I guess there should be a way to get the supported architecture of the package as well the listed .so files inside each folder. Any idea on this?

Comment: You already asked this yesterday! [Retreiving Native Code Architecture from an Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753578/retreiving-native-code-architecture-from-an-android-app).

Comment: This is for using package manager and the previous question is on using a tool or command line tool

Comment: No, your previous question also states that it is a task being performed by an app, which means that the build system tools are not available.

Comment: The tools can be external which the app needs to communicate with using SSH or telnet or sync with the cloud.

Comment: If you leave out highly unusual information like that you, then you've completely failed to ask an answerable question either here or there - which might explain why you have only 144 rep after a year of membership and 53 questions asked.

Answer (score 0):

PackageManager won't tell you this directly.

However it will tell you the filename of the app's APK file (via ApplicationInfo.sourceDir), and you can then use `ZipFile` to iterate through all the files in the apk, to get a list of the files in the libs directory tree.

See also [How to get the file *.apk location in Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635448/how-to-get-the-file-apk-location-in-android-device)